# フォルダ内の最後のファイル名を取得

Tags: python

フォルダー内に日時を元にしたファイル名のファイルが複数あるとして、
pythonで、このフォルダー内の最後のファイル名を取得するには、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

よろしく、お願いいたします。

Comment: 日時からフィル名を作成する方法を明示してください。例えば日付を８桁の数字で表す場合、日本ではyyyymmdd、アメリカではmmddyyyy、イギリスではddmmyyyyyというように書き方が違いますから、「最後」を判断する方法も異なります。月がJanのように文字で表現されることもありますし。。。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ファイル名によって解法が変わりますが、ありがちな名称の対応方法を例示します。

ファイル名が`20180118`のようにyyyymmddのみの場合

```
import os
dir = 'C:\\test'
max(os.listdir(dir))
```

`CODE99-01-18-2018.dat`のように、**固定長**のファイル名の場合

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
fs = os.listdir('C:\\test')
max(fs, key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[7:17], '%m-%d-%Y'))
```

`○○(Ver.1)議事録(Jan 18 2018).doc`のように可変長でルールが決まっているファイル名の場合

```
import os
import re
#日付判別のためdateutilを使用
from dateutil.parser import parse

def getDate(s):
    #末尾の()を日付として抽出
    d = re.findall('\((.+?)\)', s)[-1]
    return parse(d)

fs = os.listdir('C:\\test')
max(fs, key=getDate)
```